# Switch to thread using GDB

Tags: multithreading, debugging, gdb

I debug a multi thread process using GDB.

When I pause the debug to run some commands in GDB termial, how can I switch to another thread context?

When I stop debugging GDB is always on the main thread, but I want to switch for example to thread 1234

Comment: With `info threads` you get a list of all threads, and with `thread OTHER_THREAD_NUM` you can switch to another thread.

Comment: Can I switch to thread by thread name?

Comment: No, only by the thread number that gdb tells you. Most threads don't have a thread name.

Comment: @ssbssa you can write as an answer so I will give you reputation.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can get thread_id from this command, such as "helloworld" thread

```
ps -o comm,tid -T `pgrep your_process_name` | grep helloworld
helloworld 12345
```

and lookup for thread number of it in gdb

```
gdb attach `pgrep your_process_name`
thread find 12345
```

```
Thread 3 has target id 'LWP 12345'
```

then switch to it

```
thread 3
```